# What does it mean for an equillibrium to move?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

Le Chatelier's principle was described to me as:

> If a dynamic equilibrium is disturbed by changing the conditions, the position of equilibrium moves to counteract the change.

I do not understand the phrase, "*...the position of the equilibrium moves to counteract the change.*"

How can the equilibrium "*move*?" I know that the equilibrium constant cannot change so that cannot be it.

Comment: For starters, it should use the term "in response to" instead of "to counteract".

Comment: Also, I have an answer to a related question that may help provide clarity.
 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75619/can-we-force-reactions-with-positive-delta-g/98708#98708

Comment: @A.K. I'm sorry but I don't understand how that answer helps with this question. It seems beyond anything I'm learning.

Comment: Hi Leif Metcalf, welcome to Chem.SE! Your question seems to be possibly a duplicate of [What does it mean to shift equilibrium?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5486). Have a look at that question, and if it doesn't help, feel free to [edit] your question to offer more clarification, as to how your question is different from the one I linked. Thanks!

Comment: Also related: [What does “to the left” mean?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/88510) and [What is the difference between the equilibrium position and the equilibrium constant?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51732)

Comment: Not "conditions," just changing concentrations.

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep this simple. Think about adding vinegar (acetic acid) to water.

$$\ce{CH3COOH + H2O <=> H3O^+ + CH3COO^-}$$

The equilibrium equation is

$$\ce{K_a} = \dfrac{\ce{[H^+][CH3COO^-]}}{\ce{[CH3COOH]}}$$

Le Chatelier's principle simply says that if I add more acetic acid to the water then the solution gets more acidic. However if I add more water, then the solution gets less acidic. Hence the [equilibrium moves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6913KnbMpHM).(In this case it works to a point. Adding a drop of water to glacial acetic acid isn't an aqueous solution...)

Comment: It "moves", huh? ;-)

Comment: I think it is better depicted by $K_\mathrm{a}$ (acid dissociation constant) instead of $K_\mathrm{\alpha}$, isn't it?

Comment: @GaurangTandon - Thanks for pointing out blooper...